# Save PointF[] shape as image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, polygon

I have a User Control making a `PointF[]` triangle (to be used as a slider for a trackbar).

```
double hypotenuse;
double finalPoint;

public PointF Target { get; set; }
public PointF PointB { get; set; }
public PointF PointC { get; set; }

public PointF[] triangle = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0) };

public TriangleSliderUC()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);  

    PropertyConstructor();
    PointConstructor();

    Paint += new PaintEventHandler(TriangleSliderUC_Paint);
}

public void PointConstructor()
{
    Target = new PointF((int)finalPoint, (int)(hypotenuse * 0.5f));
    PointB = new PointF(0, 0);
    PointC = new PointF(0, (int)hypotenuse);

    triangle[0] = Target;
    triangle[1] = PointB;
    triangle[2] = PointC;
}

void TriangleSliderUC_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Orange, triangle);
}
```

In order to use it as a thumb for a trackbar, I want to save the created triangle as a bitmap so that it doesn't have to repaint every time it moves.

How do I do that?

Also, is there a better way to structure my code? I'm new to C# and rusty at OOP.

Comment: When doing a custom control which needs drawing, I typically inherit from `PictureBox`. Draw the image once (or redraw on property change), and then set it as the Image property. No need then for a custom Paint event.

Comment: @James thanks for the tip! Though I still don't fully understand what that is or how I'd go about it. Could you add an answer explanation or comment a link for more reading on your way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example, using what I can see of your current code. It may not be a direct replacement for what you have already developed, but should give you some ideas.

I've made `Hypotenuse` and `FinalPoint` public properies which write to a private variable, but also make the call to update the triangle image.
`UpdateTriangle` creates a blank image with the same dimensions as the control, then draws the triangle as you were doing in `PointConstructor` and `Paint` event. Finally it sets the `Image` property of the underlying Control (PictureBox).

```
public class TriangleSliderUC : PictureBox
{
    public double Hypotenuse
    {
        get { return hypotenuse; }
        set
        {
            hypotenuse = value;
            UpdateTriangle();
        }
    }
    public double FinalPoint
    {
        get { return finalPoint; }
        set
        {
            finalPoint = value;
            UpdateTriangle();
        }
    }

    private PointF[] triangle = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0) };
    private double hypotenuse;
    private double finalPoint;

    public TriangleSliderUC()
    {
        UpdateTriangle();
    }

    public void UpdateTriangle()
    {
        triangle[0] = new PointF((int)finalPoint, (int)(hypotenuse * 0.5f));
        triangle[1] = new PointF(0, 0); 
        triangle[2] = new PointF(0, (int)hypotenuse);

        // Create a new image with the current control dimensions
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

        // Create a grahics object, draw the triangle
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Orange, triangle);

        // Update the controls image with the newly created image
        this.Image = image;
    }
}
```

You may also want to add a call to the `UpdateTriangle` function from the `Resize` event if you want to scale to fit in the available space.

```
this.Resize += TriangleSliderUC_Resize;

private void TriangleSliderUC_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTriangle();
}
```